# Logistic Regression - ROC curve plots Sensitivity vs Specificity instead of (1-Specificity)

Tags: machine-learning, r, predictive-modeling, logistic-regression, model-evaluations

I am new to Machine Learning and have been doing some practice on Logistic Regression. To evaluate the models, I've been trying to create some ROC plots. 
The package that i used is pROC.

The model name is - 'model' dataset is 'data'.

The code I used in R is:

```
library(pROC)  
predictionData <- predict(model, newdata = data, type = "response")  
rocModel <- roc(data$y ~ as.numeric(predictionData>0.5))  
plot(rocModel)
```

Ideally, from what i have learned, ROC should plot Sensitivity or TPR (True Positive Rate) vs 1 - Specificity. But as shown in the picture below, it shows Sensitivity vs Specificity.

[image]

Am I missing some obvious trick here or is something wrong with what I have done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the specificity in the x-axis goes from `1.0` to `0.0` (backwards).

So the effect is the same, you are seeing 1-Specificity

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have one more related query, for an ROC, what should ideally be the threshold value for considering a probability as 1 ? Would it be 0.5 always or would it be changing based on any parameters ? TIA.

Comment: The ROC curve doesn't care about thresholds, the curve plots all the possible thresholds for a model.

Comment: In fact, the ROC curve helps you select a correct threshold for your problem. The best c (threshold) is the one which minimizes the distance between your curve and the corner (0,1)